# Where did I go wrong trying to simplify this down to $(x \times y)$ boolean expression?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

**Simplify:**

$[(x \times y') + x']' $

**My attempt:**

1. $((x \times y') + x')' $
2. $(x \times y')' \times x''$
3. $(x'+ y'') \times x''$
4. $(x' + y'') \times x$
5. $(x' + y) \times x$
6. $(x'+ y)(x' + x)$
7. $x(x' + y) + x'(x' + x)$
8. $xx'+xy+x'x'+x'x$
9. $0 + xy + x + 0$

The answer is supposed to be: $(x \times y)$

N.B. I am still new to this and learning, I am using the following book:

```
Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman
```

Comment: Now apply distributivity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, if I apply that I get $(x' + y)(x' +x)$ and then I am stuck again. Because **1** one there for x + x' doesn't work.

Comment: In step 2 to 3, I don't think you can remove the brackets like that.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, I am doing **de Morgan's law** and **Double Complement law** on those two steps.

Comment: The problem is that in 5 the brackets are suddenly put in a different spot. The problem is that  $(a+b)\times c$ is not the same as $a+(b\times c)$, so you still need the brackets around the first two terms in 3.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, hmm! 

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I added the backets on step 3.

Comment: Step from 5 to 6 now no longer makes sense. You should be applying the distributive law there.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Step 6 is based on the Distributive Law.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the freeing of y'' to y in step 5 is done with the Double Complement Law.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the issue is on step 7, where I am not sure if I should apply x' before the second parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a mistake going from 5 to 6: Applying Distribution on $(x'+y)x$ results in $x'x + yx$

Comment: **Thanks a lot. Life saver!**